The rope.bat in Rope failed to run
I got the hint when I opened rope.bat in the rope project:
D:\Rope>call conda activate Rope
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Rope\Rope.py", line 3, in <module>
    from rope import Coordinator
ImportError: cannot import name 'Coordinator' from 'rope' (C:\Users\RanjoXD\miniconda3\envs\Rope\lib\site-packages\rope\__init__.py)

I installed ffmpeg,CUDA and cudnn on my computer,
I created the conda virtual environment and entered 'python -m pip install -r requirements.txt' in pwsh
I think I had everything ready, but it just wasn't working
The contents of 'rope.bat' are as follows:
call conda activate Rope
python Rope.py 
pause

The contents of 'Rope.py' are as follows:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from rope import Coordinator
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Coordinator.run()

The contents of 'requirements.txt' are as follows:
--extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118

numpy==1.23.5
opencv-python==4.7.0.72
scikit-image==0.21.0
tk==0.1.0
pillow==9.5.0
onnx==1.14.0
onnxruntime-gpu==1.16.2
protobuf==4.23.2
torch==2.0.1+cu118
torchvision==0.15.2
torchaudio==2.0.2
tqdm
ftfy
regex

Rope's github address:
https://github.com/Hillobar/Rope

Can you review your question. I see no reference to rope.bat and no isses related to the Powershell Core tag. May be include tags for conda, python. May be also include the content of rope.py too.

@phuzi I added my question, thank you for reminding me

How did you install rope?

Could it be that you ran pip install rope instead of cloning the gitub repo?

@FlyingTeller maybe,but 'Rope' on github is this project itself.

If you look at https://github.com/Hillobar/Rope/wiki then the correct way to obtain rope is to clone the repo and then just use it. rope on PyPi is a completely different module. So I suggest you pip uninstall rope  first and then try again

I think you can try uninstall your rope package in your Rope environment with pip uninstall rope. Then when you run with python Rope.py, it will direct to the rope folder that you have pulled from github.
